# How to resume reading from BigQuery Storage API upon session timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spark-bigquery-connector, google-bigquery-storage-api

BigQuery Storage API has a 6 hours session timeout https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2#bigqueryread. While reading 100s of TBs of data with 1k maximum allowed streams 6h is not enough time to read all the data.

Given these limitations, I want to know if there is a scalable way to read large datasets from BQ via BQ Storage API? If not, are there any alternatives that scale for reading large datasets from BQ?

Comment: Have you considered splitting reading into multiple sessions by using `rowRestriction` option? I.e. read odd ids in one session and even in another, or limit by some date condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is not yet covered.

According to the current situation, you can

- run sessions up to 6 hours
- have at most 1000 streams

if you say you have a project and use case, where you cannot finish with 1000 streams in 6 hours, I would suggest contacting your Google Cloud representative and seeing if some of the above quotas can be raised for your project.

Comment: Does Spark BigQuery connector work any differently to workaround this limitation or inherit the 6h session reading up to 1k streams limit?  Don't see any mention of this limitations in https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#apache-spark-sql-connector-for-google-bigquery

Comment: Yes, they use the same API to build the connector. With that volume, you have great chance to get that raised if you reach out to your G rep.

Comment: Thanks, checking with GCP folks if that's an option. will update the thread once I hear back

Comment: @haltTm Do you have any answer from GCP? I have same problem with spark-connector.